# Copy richttextitem from docA to docB with different fieldname

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In SSJS I would like to copy richt text field from doc A to another richt text field in doc B. the fields on source and target document have different names.

How can I establish such?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: var text:NotesRichTextItem = docSettings.getFirstItem("emailBody"); email.Copyitemtodocument(text, "Body");

Comment: It looks to me as if in the second line of your code variables 'email' and 'text' are mixed up (assuming that 'email' refers to a NotesDocument object). Does it work if you put 'text.copyItemToDocument(email, "Body")'?